# Codeigniter form validation is not showing

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

for somehow my codeigniter form validation is not showing on login page
given below is my login page in view

```
            <div class="full_w">
        <p>Food4U</p>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            <?php echo form_open('staff/valid_login'); ?>
                <label for="city">Select City</label>
                <select name="city" class="text">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                    <?php echo $this->front_model->get_Fcities(); ?>
                </select>
                <label for="login">Username:</label>
                <input id="login" name="username" class="text" />
                <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                <input id="pass" name="password" type="password" class="text" />
                <div class="sep"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="ok">Login</button>
                <a class="button" href="">Change Password</a>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </form>
        </div>
```

given below are functions in controller

```
    function valid_login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|trim|xss_clean|callback_validate_credentials');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');
    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $data = array(
                'username' =>$this->input->post('username'),
                'is_loggedin' => 1
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('staff/member');
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->load->view("dashboard/login");
    }

 }

 function member()
 {   
    $row['content']=$this->load->view("dashboard/member",array(),true);
    $this->load->view("dashboard/template", $row);
 }

function validate_credentials() 
{
    if($this->staff_model->can_login())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials','Incorrect Username or Password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my model function is

```
    function can_login()
{
    $this->db->where('DB_User_City',$this->input->post('city'));
    $this->db->where('DB_User_Login',$this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('DB_User_Pass',$this->input->post('password'));

    $query= $this->db->get('frp_db_user');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

if user just click on submit button user should see a message and if user provide any single value incorrect then user must also see whats wrong with login so that user can provide correct information

Comment: When you submit form, what you get? an error or anything?

Comment: nothing display just stay on login page

Comment: Im sure, you have load form_validation library?

Comment: function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
 } // this is my __construct in controller where i have add form_validation library

Comment: you also need to load form helper, add this to your constructor "$this->load->helper('form');". The function you have used in the view "validation_errors()" is of form validation helper and not form validation library.

Comment: actually i have already loaded $this->load->helper('form') there

Comment: hmm. can you paste a var_dump() right before the the form_validation if statement? i.e add "var_dump();die(); " right before the if statement, submit the form, and give the output

Comment: parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->library('email');
  $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->load->helper('string');
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->helper('cookie');
  $this->load->model('staff_model'); i have add all the required helpers and libraries

Comment: @death_relic0 sorry i cant get ur point where should i place var_dump();die() it i need more detail i mean in my controller or view file

Comment: open the login page on your browser, then add this to the first line of your valid_login() function "print_r($this->input->post());die();" . then submit the form on your browser and paste the output you get

Comment: @death_relic0 i have done this as u said but nothing display i mean no error message display

Comment: i have following output  Array ( [city] => [username] => [password] => )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your view for each fields you set validation blow its field or some where else
write like this codes to show your validation errors.

```
      <div class="full_w">
    <p>Food4U</p>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('staff/valid_login'); ?>
            <label for="city">Select City</label>
            <select name="city" class="text">
                <option value="">Select City</option>
                <?php echo $this->front_model->get_Fcities(); ?>
            </select>
            <br />
            <?=form_error('city')?>
            <br />
            <label for="login">Username:</label>
            <input id="login" name="username" class="text" />
            <br />
            <?=form_error('username')?>
            <br />
            <label for="pass">Password:</label>
            <input id="pass" name="password" type="password" class="text" />

            <br />
            <?=form_error('password')?>
            <br />

            <div class="sep"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="ok">Login</button>
            <a class="button" href="">Change Password</a>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks ur provided solution is working but i have fix my problem with ur idea actually there is something else wrong in my controller now my validation is working

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like ok. Try this one

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{ 
    //redirect to your login form
}
else
{
    //redirect to dashboard
}
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: i have try this but still nothing happen still i got no errors display